# How to deploy custom libraries to Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, java-native-interface

If I have a custom library (coded in Scala but it internally calls native libraries via JNI), what is a way to deploy it to Apache Spark worker nodes so it can be used by other applications in the cluster? Basically, I want to extend Spark with my custom functionality so that any job can use it.

As far as I understand, spark-submit is for submitting jobs, so that is not what I want.

If I pack the native libraries in a jar, is `Context.addJar()` going to do the trick? I would have to unpack the native libraries at runtime to some temp directory for that to work - is it even an option in Spark environment?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say *"Some Scala code that calls native libraries"* do you mean that code is ran inside a Spark job?

Comment: That code should be available to be called from Spark jobs. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: You want to utilize an external library from your Spark job? Have you considered packing it inside the uber JAR of your job?

Comment: It's not about running my jobs. I want to extend Spark with my custom functionality so that any job can use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`spark-submit` takes a couple of parameters that are of interest. `--packages` and `--jars`. You can add your custom `.jar` to the `--jars` one. You can pass maven coordinates to `--packages`. Something like:

```
spark-submit ... --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.2.0 --jars localpath/to/your.jar
```

These work in the `spark-shell` too, so you can deploy your custom `jar` files and any external dependencies when you use the `REPL`.

If you have a particularly large `jar` file, you can use `SparkContext.addJar` to add it to the context. However, this is a pain to maintain. To really do it efficiently, you would need to deploy the JAR file to HDFS, and ensure that HDFS replicates it amongst all of your nodes -- if HDFS only has the JAR file on one node, you are right back where you started. And then what do you do about version control? If you change the `JAR` file, most likely you need to keep the old one around in case any jobs were coded against it, so you will need to have multiple versions in HDFS. Are you going to have the other jobs recompile to use a new version? The nice thing about `--packages` and `--jars` is that the mess of all of that is handled for you.

But assuming your custom JAR is big enough to warrant that, yes you can include it via `SparkContext.addJar`, however, like I said -- it's not the standard way to do it. Even semi-core extensions to Spark, like `spark-streaming-kafka`, are delivered via the  `--packages` option.

Comment: Would that actually deploy my library so that it can be used by other jobs? I am not trying to run my own job, but to extend Spark so that all jobs can call my library.

Comment: It's the other jobs that need to use the commands in this answer. This is how you let them deploy your custom code -- you give them your jar and let them run their command like the above (with `--jars`) or you create a `maven` artifact and give them the coordinates. If you look in my example, `spark-streaming-kafka` is an extension to Spark. You are trying to do exactly what it is doing -- extending Spark -- and this is the standard way to do it.

Comment: But wouldn't the jar get copied on each new job then? Ideally, I'd have it "installed" on each worker node and ready to be used by other jobs.

Comment: I mean, how big is the library you're talking about? Is it a gigabytes, megabytes, or a couple of hundred K?

Comment: It's hundreds of Mbs. Thanks for the answer! Is calling the native code packed in the jar going to be a problem in Spark? Security, etc?

Comment: Don't know -- I use lots of external libraries included via `--packages` and never had an issue, but that doesn't mean you never will.

Comment: @NemanjaTrifunovic Did you get it to work eventually? I have a spark app that uses a JNI call, so I packaged the whole think in the Docker container, but now I receive UnsatisfiedLinkError about my native method stub

Comment: @Yar No. It was a long time a go, but I am pretty sure I ended up pre-installing the external lib to the worker nodes